# How to unstack observations and arrange them in columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, feature-extraction, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I have a dataframe like below, the row number is identical with all XX YY ZZ variables,

```
Name date    Value 
XX   01/20     69
XX   02/20     75
YY   01/20     450
YY   02/20     430
ZZ   01/20     1000
ZZ   02/20     899
```

how to convert it into

```
date      XX   YY   ZZ 
01/20     69  450   1000
02/20     75  430   899
```

You notice that value column is gone, and all values became observations under XX YY ZZ Features.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please input dataframes as actual text, rather than images. Makes it easier for others to copy+paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use pivot:

```
df.pivot(index='date', columns='Name', values='Value')
```